# while web frameworks implemented security measures, is it necessary to install WAF on webserver?

Tags: django, security, web-application-firewall

while modern web frameworks such as Yii (PHP), Laravel (PHP), Django (python) and etc have implemented security measures against attacks on web application such as XSS, SQL injection, RFI and etc, is it necessary to install a WAF on webserver?

i deployed a project with django and nginx, i want to know is that necessary or not?

Comment: Django will cover XSS, CSRF and SQL injection. It's not necessary, just a bit redundant.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_(computing)